# Bilinear interpolation of angles

Tags: trigonometry, interpolation

Is their a solution to do a bilinear interpolation in x,y of angles in [0°-360°[ ? The elementary formula of bilinear interpolation don't work on angles due to the discontinuity at 360°-0°.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_interpolation

I have found a formula the mean of angles but it doesn't seems usefull for bilinear interpolation of angles.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_of_circular_quantities#Mean_of_angles

Comment: Bilinear interpolation of angles?  You have... two components of angle?  Or just one?

Comment: I have a lattice in x,y with angles values at each point of the lattice and I have to interpolate the angle at some point inside the lattice.

Comment: Oh I see.  Okay, for the bilinear part, you can simply apply the linear interpolation multiple times.  As for interpolation of angle... if you have angles themselves, you can adjust the angle locations so they're less than half a circle apart, which (when adjustment needs to be made, about half the time) puts the adjusted angle outside the fundamental circle... but that's perfectly okay.

Comment: What is the adjustment? do you mean adjust it in ]-180°,+180°] when more than 180° ?

Comment: The adjustment is something like: if $|a-b| >$ half a circle, add a whole circle of angle to the lower of the two.  Then linear interpolation will give you values that are "above" the fundamental circle but that's okay; you can readjust them as you see fit later.

Answer (score 4):

I think I finally have enough information from OP to know what he or she is talking about.

Imagine that the world is an flat sheet of paper.  The wind blows through this world, defining a vector field. We can model this as a function $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$.  In other words, we have $f(x,y) = (U(x,y),V(x,y))$.

Assume we only know the value of $f$ at four points the fours points $$(x_0,y_0), (x_0,y_1),(x_1,y_0),(x_1,y_1)$$

We want to approximate the value of $f$ at all points interior to the rectangle by "bilinear interpolation":  in other words, we can interpolate linearly along the top and bottom edge, and then interpolate linearly again through these values.

**There is no problem here**:  just use the standard formula for bilinear interpolation on $U(x,y)$ and $V(x,y)$ separately.

The problem comes when you try to approach this problem in polar coordinates:  if you want to bilinearly interpolate angles, you run into the topological problems I mention in the answer on MO (essentially you run into the fact that the mobius strip cannot retract onto its boundary circle).

So my solution is to simply avoid the angles, and work directly with the actual vector field.

If for some reason you did not have the magnitude information, but only the angle information, you would be kind of sunk.  One thing you could do in this case is to imagine that the magnitudes are all $1$, convert to rectangular coordinates, and implement my method above.  This circumvents the topological obstruction because we can allow $f(a,b) = (0,0)$, which does not correspond to an angle.

**Moral of the story**: when modeling wind, it is possible that you will need the wind to be stationary sometimes.  In other words $f(x,y)=(0,0)$ for some $(x,y)$.  This does not have a well defined angle measurement, so it kind of sucks to try and model this in polar coordinates.  Much better to stick to rectangular coordinates, which do not have this pathological behavior.

Comment: If you really only have access to angle data, then instead of assuming constant wind speed (which is unlikely), you could do something a little more sophisticated by assuming that the air is acting like an incompressible fluid.  Then the function you are modeling will be holomorphic when thought of as a map from $\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$, and you can recover the magnitude data from the angle data!  Basically you would be trying to solve the Cauchy Riemann equations numerically.

Comment: It doesn't belongs to my problem: I have to interpolate real data measurements (wind strength and direction separately ) on some point inside the grid. The data stats rely to a max of 32° between two points of the grid.

Comment: Why do you have to interpolate them separately?  If you have access to both, then combine them into rectangular coordinates, and use my approach.  In other words, if you have $r$ and $\theta$, convert to the vector $(r\cos(\theta),r\sin(\theta))$, and bilinearly interpolate both the x coordinate and the y coordinate.  If you like, you can then convert back to polar, but as I keep repeatedly saying, you will run into problems if your interpolation passes through $(0,0)$, since there is a singularity in the transformation from rectangular to polar at this point.

Comment: It is unnatural to be averaging angles anyway:  physically the velocities add, not the angles.  My solution is more physically relevant.

Comment: The coords of the grid points are not in (r,θ) coordinates but in (lat, long, altipressure) which is of best use. So I'd better have to interpolate it separately.

Comment: What is altipressure?  How could you possibly get an angle out of a pressure?  I am really trying to help you here, but you are just not being clear at all about what data you have and what you are trying to accomplish. I recommend editting your OP to include some sample data.  For example, give the data you actually have at 4 points of a rectangle.

Comment: my comment about 32° is not clear: it's 32° difference max of the value of wind angle between 2 points of the grid. Altipressure is an altitude measurement where equilevels of altitude have the same pressure value. It's the standard coordinates system in meteo.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17070/discussion-between-steven-gubkin-and-bilbo).

Answer (score 1):

Standard bilinear interpolation goes like this:  Given the values $a=f(0,0)$, $b=f(1,0)$, $c=f(0,1)$, and $d=f(1,1)$, the value of $f(x,y)$ can be found as:
$$j=(1-x)a+xb$$
$$k=(1-x)c+xd$$
$$f(x,y)=(1-y)j+yk$$
Now, when working in a circular realm, we wish to take the short way around; sometimes, this is not the way that interpolates between $a$ and $b$ as numbers!  This happens when $|a-b|>$ half a circle.

To fix this, in places where we need to interpolate around a circle, we can simply add a whole circle ($360°$ or $2\pi$) to the smaller of the two values when they're too far apart as described above.  There are three such places, and three such pairs of values: $(a, b)$, $(c,d)$ and $(j,k)$.

Now the bad news: this will give crazy answers when $j$ and $k$ end up passing directly opposite each other.  To see this, try $a=45°$, $b=135°$, $c=315°$, and $d=225°$.

Comment: My answer to the same question at MO shows that "crazy answers" are unavoidable.  There is a topological obstruction to continuous interpolation in this case.

Comment: @StevenGubkin can you link to that answer?

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/180448/bilinear-interpolation-of-angles-in-0%C2%B0-360%C2%B0/180453#comment452454_180453

Comment: @StenveGubkin I can tell you the reverse as you tell me on the other site: it's not the place here for theory on abstaction in maths but for practical problems solutions.If this method is wrong, give me a counter-example.

Comment: @StevenGubkin My question belongs to a meteorogical application where there is a grid of wind strength and direction. Do you think there is solution on meteo grid without the wind?

Comment: @bilbo essentially, you will always run into the problem that trying to "average" two opposite angles cannot be done consistently.  If you know that your angles will always be "close" to each other, then you can have a solution.  If you admit the possibility that the angles could be quite far apart then you will always run into this problem.  There is nothing abstract about it.

Comment: The problem in my application was to interpolate values around the discontinuity at 0°=360° and the solution of  Dan Uznanski seems to solve the problem.

Comment: did you miss his "now the bad news"?

Comment: No but I don't have so large gaps values in the grid

Comment: I have added an answer which may be relevant to you.